# Помогите заполнить массив не дублируя значения

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет!

Такое дело, я достаю из базы id товара и колличество купленного товара и добавляю его в массив, выглядит это так:

```
$item_array[] = [
                item_id => $item_id,
                item_count => $item_count
            ];
```

В дальнейшем из базы может выпасть тот же самый id товара, но нельзя допустить чтобы товар дублировался, если товар потворяется то нужно суммировать колличество купленного товара, как мне это лучше сделать?

Буду рад любому совету! Спасибо!

Comment: лучше это сделать в запросе к БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В дополнение к ответу про перенос этой логики в БД, приведу решение на php.*

Чтобы не дублировать вновь поступающие значения в массиве, проще всего использовать ассоциативный массив с подходящим ключом:

```
if (!isset($item_array[$item_id])) {
  $item_array[$item_id] = ['item_id' => $item_id, 'item_count' => 0];
}
$item_array[$item_id]['item_count'] += $item_count;
```

Позже, ключи можно сбросить:

```
$item_array = array_values($item_array);
```

Answer (score 6):

Надо использовать правильные инструменты, которые все будут делать за тебя.

Суммировать должна база данных. Для этого в запросе пишем

```
SELECT item_id, sum(item_count) FROM table GROUP BY item_id
```

Массив заполнять тоже должна программа, а не программист (тем более так коряво как в вышеприведенном коде

```
$item_array = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Все было бы здорово, но на сайте 13 языков, id товара может быть разный в базе(в зависимости с какого языка покупали товар) 

В тот момент когда я получаю id товара, мне приходиться доставать английский id этого товара, в общем геморрой, но как мне это сделать уже после того как я вытащил из базы?

Comment: Кроме оператора GROUP BY в SQL еще есть оператор JOIN